# How to search a text field for multiple possible values in JIRA

Tags: jql

According to the Atlassian documentation, you can search for words contained in a text field like so:

```
description ~ term
```

It also indicates you can group terms like so:

```
description ~ (term OR "different thing")
```

But when I try that, it shows that the syntax is wrong.

I want to do this, but with grouping (because I will have more than 2 terms, and I'd like to keep the query easy to read and short-ish):

```
description ~ term OR description ~ "different thing"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

description doesn’t support lists...

[image]

description doesn’t support = operator....

[image]

I think you already have the best answer to your question with JQL, by using....

```
description ~ “term” OR description ~ “different thing”
```

Although, a list method would work for the priority field, the list option isn’t available for every field...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the supporting screenshots.  Based on their documentation, it seems like it should work, but it clearly does not.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Actually the multi-text match search phrase that worked for me was this example:

```
text ~ "(uc55 OR uc60 OR UC65)"
```

Comment: This works for a custom text field in our system. "Customer Number" = "(1234 OR 1235)" returns tickets with customer number matching either 1234 or 1235.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to do what you want:

```
description ~ ("term OR different thing")
```

Comment: I tried that, and it's valid, but the query doesn't give expected results